# IBM AppCenter Console displaying default app icon instead of actual app icon from ipa

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

When i am deploying `ipa file` on `IBM AppCenter console`, it display default app icon instead of picking the actual icon from `ipa file`.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, if the app plist file don't have app name "CFBundleDisplayName" then server throw exception and will not execute code for identifying icon from ipa file.